# How can I enable eth1 for my Cloudera VM on Mac1?

Tags: macos, hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, apple-m1

I am using Mac M1 for running my Hadoop cluster **using docker container**. In the image shown below I have docker container from my container in which Cloudera VM is running. I have been trying to connect to the Cloudera instance via FileZilla. I am unable to connect to eth0 IP address so I want to enable eth1 so that I can connect to it from FileZilla as I do in my Windows system.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to proceed with the process so that I can enable eth1 on my docker container and then connect to filezilla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your output shows, there is only one eth network interface, so there is nothing to enable to add another one.

It is possible FileZilla cannot connect because your Docker container and/or VM does not expose port 22 for SFTP. Also, you shouldn't need a VM on a Mac to run any containers unless Cloudera doesn't publish ARM images.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my concept. I am able to connect via filezilla now.